# Google maps is not working on my IPhone 5S the last 2 days when on LTE

Tags: iphone, google-maps

For the last 2 days when on LTE, my Google Maps will load the data, but once it comes up, it's immediately deleted.  It's only Google Maps I have trouble with, as my Gmail comes up without problem

Comment: You know the native Maps app has gotten a lot better over the last few iOSes, better than Google Maps. It'd just be easier for you to use Maps.

Answer (score -1):

I have not met with this problem before, but i suggest that you can uninstall Google maps and download it again